# Importing data from one spreadsheet to another without the import range function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to build this database and have the database connect to a different spreadsheet. I am trying to import the id's of different client from the database spreadsheet into another spreadsheet.

But I keep on getting this error message:

```
Bad value (line 6, file "Code")Dismiss
```

line 6 is:

```
var targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Control Panel");
```

`function logMemberId () {`

`var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Database");`

`var targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Control Panel");`

 `var rangeOfNumbers = ss.getRange("A2:A100").getValues();`

 `targetSpreadsheet.getRange("B3").setValues(rangeOfNumbers);
}`

Comment: What I want to do is for the numbers from the database to autopopulate in the control panel spreadsheet and then run the script to obtain what i need.

Answer (score 0):

```
var targetSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxxx");
```

xxxx needs to be the ID that you find in the URL of the document. For example, in this document
[image]
it is "1kvrEKMXLLq4mQ-Uhlc6tOJnh5cReiRIcD94fJKSNlIw"

"Control Panel" is likely the title of your document and not the ID.

Comment: Well if somebody else were to open this file on their computer, will the key remain a constant? I think it will change right?

Comment: As I said: "for example". Yes, you need to replace the ID with the one in your Google drive that you desire to write to. You should not be using the title (e.g. 'Control Panel'). You can only use a string to find a Sheet (tab) within a Spreadsheet.